# JAVA Swing GridLayout not working properly

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

Below is the image that will clearly define my problem while using `GridLayout`

[image]

```
private void init() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextField loginUNTextField = new JTextField();
    JTextField loginPTextField = new JTextField();

    JTextField registerUNTextField = new JTextField();
    JTextField registerPTextField = new JTextField();
    JTextField registerETextField = new JTextField();

    JButton login = new JButton("Login");
    JButton register = new JButton("Register");

    JLabel loginUsername = new JLabel("Username");
    JLabel loginPassword = new JLabel("Password");

    JLabel registerUsername = new JLabel("Username");
    JLabel registerPassword = new JLabel("Password");
    JLabel registerEmail = new JLabel("Email");

    JPanel loginUNPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));

    loginUNPanel.add(loginUsername);
    loginUNPanel.add(loginUNTextField);

    loginUNPanel.add(loginPassword);  // Cause Problem
    loginUNPanel.add(loginPTextField);

    loginUNPanel.add(new JLabel(""));  // Cause Problem
    loginUNPanel.add(login);

    JPanel registerUNPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,2));

    registerUNPanel.add(registerUsername);
    registerUNPanel.add(registerUNTextField);

    registerUNPanel.add(registerPassword);
    registerUNPanel.add(registerPTextField);

    registerUNPanel.add(registerEmail);
    registerUNPanel.add(registerETextField);

    registerUNPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    registerUNPanel.add(register);

    loginUNPanel.add(loginPassword);

    JPanel main = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));

    main.add(loginUNPanel);
    main.add(registerUNPanel);

    frame.add(main);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

**Desire Result:**

```
UserName | TextField
Passowrd | TextField
         | LoginButon
```

Please let me know where I am worng using `GridLayout`.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. Consider re-checking the display from this code. Note that I added `main` to the JFrame, `frame`, called `pack()` on `frame` and then called `setVisible(true)` on frame. Please show just a little more code.

Comment: Well actually I have another Grid for registration ... Let me update my question with that code. May be that would be problem.

Comment: That image doesn't "clearly define your problem." What is the desired result if that isn't it?

Comment: Very useful new information, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding a component twice to the container.

```
  JPanel loginUNPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));

  loginUNPanel.add(loginUsername);
  loginUNPanel.add(loginUNTextField);

  loginUNPanel.add(loginPassword);  // ***** adding it once ***** 
  loginUNPanel.add(loginPTextField);

  loginUNPanel.add(new JLabel(""));  
  loginUNPanel.add(login);

  JPanel registerUNPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,2));

  registerUNPanel.add(registerUsername);
  registerUNPanel.add(registerUNTextField);

  registerUNPanel.add(registerPassword);
  registerUNPanel.add(registerPTextField);

  registerUNPanel.add(registerEmail);
  registerUNPanel.add(registerETextField);

  registerUNPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
  registerUNPanel.add(register);

  loginUNPanel.add(loginPassword);  // ***** adding it again. ***** 

  JPanel main = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
```

Get rid of that 2nd addition:

```
// loginUNPanel.add(loginPassword);  // *** this

JPanel main = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
```

Comment: @Junaid: sometimes you just need another pair of eyes to look over the code. Glad it's working.